# NSArrays in NSArrays. A pointer problem?

Tags: cocoa, pointers, nsarray

I believe my problem involves pointers, a concept I often struggle with, but here's what I'm trying to do.

I have six NSArrays. I want an additional NSArray comprised of these six arrays, so:

```
self.arr1 = [NSArray array];
self.arr2 = [NSArray array];
self.arr3 = [NSArray array];
self.arr4 = [NSArray array];
self.arr5 = [NSArray array];
self.arr6 = [NSArray array];

NSArray *containerArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.arr1, ... etc, nil];
```

Whenever I update one of the first 6 NSArrays, I want the object updated in containerArray. (I know I'm using an NSArray and not an NSMutableArray, when I update the arrays I create a new one and assign it to the instance variable).

Currently, any manipulation of arr1 is not reflected in [containerArray objectAtIndex:0].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because your instance variables `self.arr1`, `self.arr2` are placeholders for a variable of type `NSArray`, but when you update them you just lose the old reference that still remains in the `containerArray`.

To explain better:

```
self.arr1 <------ [NSArray array] (the first one you create)
```

then you build up the `contentArray` and you have:

```
self.arr1 <--------------------------+-- [NSArray array] (first one you create)
                                     |
[contentArray objectAtIndex:0] <-----+
```

after you create your `contentArray` and you assign the arrays to it you have duplicated references. `self.arr1` will point to the same array pointed by first element of `contentArray` and so on for others.

Then you update `self.arr1 = [NSArray array]` with a new array so what you obtain is

```
self.arr1 <------------ [NSArray array] (new one created)

[contentArray objectAtIndex:0] <----- [NSArray array] (the old one)
```

So what's happened?

You created a new array and assigned it to `self.arr1`. So `self.arr1` will point to the new item while `[contentArray objectAtIndex:0]` will still reference to the old one. Every modification to `self.arr1` will be not reflected on the other one because they are **NOT** the same object.

This because you are using *references* to objects and not plain objects. When you assign a new array to `self.arr1` you are not modifying the old one but discarding the reference to it for a new one that replaces the old one.

That's why you should use a `NSMutableArray`: because in that case you would remove/add elements to the same array, without creating a new one.

Comment: That was thorough. Thanks very much! I see what you're saying. I may need to rethink what I'm trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `NSArray` will provide you with the behaviour you want, since it maintains strong references to the objects you give it. From the [NSArray Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html):

> Arrays maintain strong references to their contents—in a managed memory environment, each object receives a retain message before its id is added to the array and a release message when it is removed from the array or when the array is deallocated.

And in the meantime it looks like Jack posted the explanation I was about to give, so I'll leave it at that.

Answer (score 0):

If you used mutable arrays for the individual arrays instead of creating new ones and re-assigning them, things would behave more like you're expecting.